# how to show long text with more button using angular?

Tags: html, angularjs

i have long text like that :-

"5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experience5 Simple Steps to Improve Patient Experienc
"

But i need only 2 line to show on page and a more button to check complete text.
Is this posible with angular.js ?

if yes What would you suggest  me ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, this is totally possible with AngularJS -- but most of the solution is actually CSS.

You'll be able to do this mostly through CSS. First, HTML/CSS doesn't really have a concept for how many lines a bunch of text is taking up. You can get the behavior you want by setting the height of a container element and the line-height of your text on the CSS `line-height`. For your default state, set the height based on two times your line height and set the `overflow` to hidden. Then you just need have your button conditionally apply a class that expands the height of the container and sets the `overflow` to visible:

```
<style>
    .container {
         font-size: 16px;
         line-height: 16px;
         height: 32px;
         overflow: hidden;
    }
    .show {
         overflow: visible;
         height: auto;
    }
<div class="container" ng-class="{show: show}">
    [your text]
</div>
<button ng-click="show = true">Show text</button>
```

You can get fancy and make the button also hide the text again (as a toggle).

Comment: I want to show the "Show text" button only when the text actually overflows and hide it if it doesn't. How can we do that? @Benmj

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I love how I can just forward this to my designer who asked me today that exact question. However your example would be even better if you would choose a different name for the scope variable and the css class. To people not so familiar with programming, which 'show' is which,  might not be as clear as you think ;-)

Answer (score 9):

ng-text-truncate
https://github.com/lorenooliveira/ng-text-truncate

Demo 1
https://rawgit.com/lorenooliveira/ng-text-truncate/master/demo1.html

Example
`<p ng-text-truncate="longTextVariable" 
    ng-tt-chars-threshold="40"></p>`

Answer (score 5):

angular-read-more
https://github.com/ismarslomic/angular-read-more

Demo
http://codepen.io/ismarslomic/pen/yYMvrz

```
<div hm-read-more
        hm-text="{{ text }}" 
        hm-limit="100" 
        hm-more-text="read more" 
        hm-less-text="read less"
        hm-dots-class="dots"
        hm-link-class="links">
</div>
```

Comment: Good one Thanks :)

Comment: @GopalRohila It doesn't look possible to put Read More and Read Less on the next line with the current functionality, looks like you'll have to edit the "readmore.template.html" file in the source code and add a linebreak: https://github.com/ismarslomic/angular-read-more/blob/master/src/readmore.template.html

Answer (score 3):

If you'd prefer to have a `div` that truncates itself based on pixel height instead of character count, you can try this. This allows you to put nested HTML in your expandable section.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.loremIpsum = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';
})
.directive('showMore', function() {
  return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        template: [
            '<div class="show-more-container"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
            '<a href="#" class="show-more-expand">More</a>',
            '<a href="#" class="show-more-collapse">Less</a>',
        ].join(''),
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            var maxHeight = 45;
            var initialized = null;
            var containerDom = element.children()[0];
            var $showMore = angular.element(element.children()[1]);
            var $showLess = angular.element(element.children()[2]);

            scope.$watch(function () {
                // Watch for any change in the innerHTML. The container may start off empty or small,
                // and then grow as data is added.
                return containerDom.innerHTML;
            }, function () {
                if (null !== initialized) {
                    // This collapse has already been initialized.
                    return;
                }

                if (containerDom.clientHeight <= maxHeight) {
                    // Don't initialize collapse unless the content container is too tall.
                    return;
                }

                $showMore.on('click', function () {
                    element.removeClass('show-more-collapsed');
                    element.addClass('show-more-expanded');
                    containerDom.style.height = null;
                });

                $showLess.on('click', function () {
                    element.removeClass('show-more-expanded');
                    element.addClass('show-more-collapsed');
                    containerDom.style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
                });

                initialized = true;
                $showLess.triggerHandler('click');
            });
        },
  };
});
```

```css
.show-more-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.show-more-collapse, .show-more-expand {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

.show-more-expanded > .show-more-collapse {
    display: inherit;
}

.show-more-collapsed > .show-more-expand {
    display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestController">
  <div show-more>
    All sorts of <strong>stuff</strong> can go in here.
    {{ loremIpsum }}
    <div>Even more divs</div>.
  </div>
  
  <div show-more>
    This <strong>won't</strong> truncate.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I add the angular code to an ionic 2 project? I tried doing this from the command line: ionic g directive showMore, but the code it produces has completely different syntax as this example.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an easier way.
Just replace `{{text}}` with `{{text | limitTo: 150}}`, and then create below simple *read more* link.