# Displaying only limited amount of text containing HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use AngularJS and I'm searching for a method that will allow me to break my HTML markup and display only 10 lines of it, with link "...see more" at the end. So for example I have something like this

```
<div ng-bind-html="myText | cutText"></div>
```

Where `cutText` is the filter that will do what I described above.
I know I can use some ways like counting letters etc. but it obviously won't go well with HTML and I can end up with broken links and `img` tags etc.
Also I know I can use regular expressions to determine tags, but I just wonder if there is simple, Anulgarjs way to complete this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to show long text with more button using angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174110/how-to-show-long-text-with-more-button-using-angular)

Comment: If you can please let us know which angular version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. I created a property to maintain the limit value and change it based on the button click. You can create a `component` or `directive` using below code and make it re-usable.

```js
(() => {
  let app = angular.module('myapp', []);
  
  app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', ($scope) => {
   $scope.content = 'Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.';
    
    $scope.limit = 20;
    
    $scope.showMore = () => {
      $scope.limit = 1000;
    }
    
    $scope.showLess = () => {
      $scope.limit = 20;
    }
  }]);
})();
```

```css
a {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">

  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    {{ content | limitTo: limit}}
    
    <a id="showMore" ng-if="limit===20" ng-click="showMore()" href="#">Show More</a>
    
    <a id="showLess" ng-if="limit!==20" ng-click="showLess()" href="#">Show Less</a>
  </div>

</div>
```